# How to store html2canvas generated image in website

Tags: html2canvas

I am new to html2canvas. So please don't mind if I am asking silly question. I can generate image using html2canvas.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#save_image_locally').click(function(){ 
        html2canvas($('#html-content-holder'), { 
            onrendered: function (canvas) { 
                var a = $("<a>").attr("href", canvas.toDataURL('image/png')) .attr("download", "download.png").appendTo("body"); 
                a[0].click(); 
                a.remove(); 
            }
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Yes you can generate an image using html2canvas. What is your question exactly? What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please be as specific as possible as this will attract better answers.

Comment: Thank you. I can generate image and download it. But cant save it to server for send links to my users. My code: $(document).ready(function() { $('#save_image_locally').click(function(){ html2canvas($('#html-content-holder'), { onrendered: function (canvas) { var a = $("<a>").attr("href", canvas.toDataURL('image/png')) .attr("download", "download.png") .appendTo("body"); a[0].click(); a.remove(); } }); }); });

Comment: @AlokRoutray add the code to your question, not as a comment.

Comment: You can save the `canvas.toDataURL()` to database, and send that as a link to the users

Comment: @crazy-ljuba I didn't get anything you suggested. Please help me how to save canvas.toDataURL() to database.